# Google Maps setCenter Specific Map

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have Google maps within jQuery UI tabs. Which means that the maps are initially hidden until the user changes tab. When that happend I trigger the resize event on the newly displayed map to display the tiles and have the map work normally. This works well and I'm doing that part like this

That function is called when the jQuery tab is switched, refreshing the newly visible map.

The problem is that the map is not centered on the marker, so apart from calling `'resize'` event, I also need to center the map as well. 
But how do I center the map within the newly visible container only, and not any others? I tried adding `this.setCenter(latlng);` below the resize event, but that doesn't work.

If you click "show" button the first map is instantly displayed, I call the resize event and that loads the tiles, but you can see that it's not centered to the element marker.

Answer (score 0):

I think you were overthinking the issue, I refactored your code and reused what you already had to make it work as expected, all you had to do was call the same function on the element when it is displayed on the screen

working example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OyGLxV?editors=001

so basically:

```
$("button").on("click", function() {
  $(".google-maps-embed").toggle();
  // refresh
  $(".google-maps-embed").each(function() {
     createMap(this);
  });
});
```

and you createMap function would be

```
function createMap(el) {
        var $this = $(el);
        var data = $this.data();
        map = new google.maps.Map(el);

        var scrollzoom = data.scrollzoom;
        var hidecontrols = data.hidecontrols;
        var zoom = data.zoom;
        var lat = data.lat || 40.7577;
        var lng = data.lng || -73.9857;
        var marker = data.usemarker;
        latlng = {lat:lat, lng:lng};

        map.setOptions({
            scrollwheel: scrollzoom || false,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
            disableDefaultUI: hidecontrols || false,
            zoom: zoom || 10
        });

        if( marker == true ) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: {lat:lat, lng:lng},
                map: map
            });
        }

        // refresh maps
        google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, "idle", function() {
            google.maps.event.trigger(this, "resize");
            this.setCenter(latlng);
        });

        $this.addClass("map-initialized");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `this` inside the "show" handler is not a `google.maps.Map`

```
// show
$("button").on("click", function() {
  $(".google-maps-embed").show();
  // refresh
  var hiddenGmap = $(".google-maps-embed");
  hiddenGmap.each(function() {
    google.maps.event.trigger(this, "resize"); // TRIGGER RESIZE
    // SET CENTER ALSO, BUT HOW?
  });
});
```

To recenter the map, you need to keep a reference to the map object around, you do have one global `map` variable, but you have two maps, so that is overwritten and can't be used to access the first `map`.

One option would be to create an array of `google.maps.Map` objects and iterate through them, save the initial center as a property of the map (in this case `._initCenter`).  You could also use a unique identify to index the array.

[working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/f8kf3vu5/3/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var maps = [];

function GMapsInit() {
  GMapsLoaded = true;
  $(".google-maps-embed").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var data = $this.data();
    var map = new google.maps.Map(this);
    maps.push(map);

    var scrollzoom = data.scrollzoom;
    var hidecontrols = data.hidecontrols;
    var zoom = data.zoom;
    var lat = data.lat || 40.7577;
    var lng = data.lng || -73.9857;
    var marker = data.usemarker;
    latlng = {
      lat: lat,
      lng: lng
    };

    map.setOptions({
      scrollwheel: scrollzoom || false,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
      disableDefaultUI: hidecontrols || false,
      zoom: zoom || 10
    });
    map._initCenter = map.getCenter();

    if (marker === true) {
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: {
          lat: lat,
          lng: lng
        },
        map: map
      });
    }

    // refresh maps
    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, "idle", function() {
      google.maps.event.trigger(this, "resize");
      this.setCenter(latlng);
    });

    $this.addClass("map-initialized");
  });
}
GMapsInit();

// show
$("button").on("click", function() {
  $(".google-maps-embed").show(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < maps.length; i++) {
      google.maps.event.trigger(maps[i], "resize"); // TRIGGER RESIZE
      maps[i].setCenter(maps[i]._initCenter);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<h1>HIDDEN MAP IS CENTERED (marker at map center)</h1>

<div class="google-maps-embed" data-pb-element data-pb-options data-pb-topbottomspacing-option data-pb-element-versions="2" data-pb-no-url data-pb-no-img-option data-pb-no-css-option data-pb-height-option="Map Height" data-hidecontrols="false" data-scrollzoom="false"
data-lat="40.7577" data-lng="-73.9857" data-zoom="13" data-usemarker="true" data-clone-no data-pb-element-type="embed-element" style="width:100%; height: 450px; display: none;"></div>
<button>SHOW</button>

<h1>VISIBLE MAP</h1>

<div class="google-maps-embed" data-pb-element data-pb-options data-pb-topbottomspacing-option data-pb-element-versions="2" data-pb-no-url data-pb-no-img-option data-pb-no-css-option data-pb-height-option="Map Height" data-hidecontrols="false" data-scrollzoom="false"
data-lat="40.7577" data-lng="-73.9857" data-zoom="13" data-usemarker="true" data-clone-no data-pb-element-type="embed-element" style="width:100%; height: 450px;"></div>
```

Comment: But this still effects the other map. I simply want to center the map that was just shown.

Comment: Then you will need to give the map a unique identifier.

Comment: Like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/f8kf3vu5/5/), also only does the `.show()`  on the map that is hidden.